# Scaling surface changes colors

Tags: pygame, scale

I'm building a pixel art game with pygame, and I'd like to scale it to double the size. I have tried the `pygame.transform` methods like `scale` and `scale2x`, but they seem to alter the colors quite badly, there's an added red hue. Is there a way to scale pixel art correctly in pygame? Basically making each pixel 2x2 of the same color. Or do I have to do it manually, if yes, any suggestions?

This is the setup I have currently, "works" but messes up the colors:

```
#set scaling
scaling = 1

screen = pygame.Surface( (screen_w, screen_h) )
window = pygame.display.set_mode( (screen_w * scaling, screen_h * scaling) )

while not done:

    #do things...

    pygame.transform.scale(screen, (screen_w * scaling, screen_h * scaling), window)
    pygame.display.update()
```

E. for reference, here's what happens.

**No pygame scaling**

[image: No scaling]

**vs. pygame scaling**

[image: Scaling]

Answer (score 2):

Your `screen` and `window` surfaces don't have the same **pixel format**. One of them is most likely RGB, and the other is BGR. When you use the optimised `scale`/`scale2x` functions passing the `window` as the destination surface, no pixel format conversions are done, so all your reds become blue (or oranges become cyan), and vice versa.

If you do it the slow, normal way as [Nick Jarvis suggested](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/98070/26250), you won't see this problem because `pygame.Surface.blit` does the conversion for you, hiding the problem.

What you should do is [`convert()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert) or [`convert_alpha()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert_alpha) your surfaces to match the output surface - `window` in your case. From the documentation:

> Creates a new copy of the Surface with the pixel format changed. The new pixel format can be determined from another existing Surface. Otherwise depth, flags, and masks arguments can be used, similar to the pygame.Surface() call.
>
> **If no arguments are passed the new Surface will have the same pixel format as the display Surface**. This is always the fastest format for blitting. **It is a good idea to convert all Surfaces before they are blitted many times**.
>
> The converted Surface will have no pixel alphas. They will be stripped if the original had them. See Surface.convert_alpha() for preserving or creating per-pixel alphas.

That is, do this:

```
# no; pixel format will be different
screen = pygame.Surface( (screen_w, screen_h) ) 

# yes
screen = pygame.Surface( (screen_w, screen_h) ).convert()
```

Comment: Yes! This is the only answer that actually properly gives the reasoning behind the issues the OP is having.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... scale2x should be exactly what you want according to the documentation... Are you sure that the added red hue isn't due to there being more pixels of that colour and the shade you've chosen just stands out more? You might want to rule out your graphics card as being the problem by testing on another machine.

You could try resizing your scene with another library, or have a go at writing your own (probably way more of a pain in the ass than it's worth). You could apply a filter to reduce the redness, but that's more of a bandaid that a real fix. Actually, have you tried fiddling around with *set_smoothscale_backend* and seeing if that changes anything?

Last resort, if you're always going to want your scene drawn twice as big you can convert all your assets with a little script to make them that way. Just sample each pixel and draw it to a texture that's twice as large with each pixel being drawn at twice their original position ([1,1] -> [2,2], [3,9] -> [6, 18]) and then fill in the three pixels nearby the same colour (red: [6, 18], [6, 19], [7, 18], [7, 19]). Save those textures to file and use those as your assets (would be way too slow to do every frame). All of your current in game co-ordinates would have to be doubled as well, unfortunately.

Comment: I haven't had the time to fiddle around with other things yet, I'll have to try. I edited the question with pics for reference, the colors are just going nuts basically, e.g. look at the shirt of the dude. Last resort of course is to just scale the actual image files.

Comment: Lol, that's way broken. I'd try building the library again from source, or downloading the previous version of Pygame and seeing if that changes anything. xD if you resize to half-size does it get less red?

Comment: It's the same colors every time. The example above is just 1x scaling, 2x and others give the same result. Funny thing...

Answer (score 0):

I've used pygame extensively, and I have had problems with scale before. Have you tried not using destination surface and instead setting the returned function to another variable like:

```
scaled_screen = pygame.transform.scale(screen, (screen_w * scaling, screen_h * scaling))
```

Then blitting that to the window at (0, 0)?

It also might be easier to scale each tile (as it looks like you are using isometric tiles) and then scaling the position of each tile. The coloring may come from scaling the whole image rather than the subsequent elements.

And just to make sure: is there anywhere in your program that may be inverting the colors of the image?

Comment: I would assume that blitting the whole thing every frame would destroy my framerate, so I guess that's not an option. If I get to that point, I'll probably have to scale each element when the images are loaded and  then just add the scaling factor to every position etc. there is.

Comment: That is what you are doing anyways when you blit to a destination surface

Comment: With the built-in scale functions? Yes. The thing is, I'm using dirty rects now. So if in the end I blit and update the full game screen anyway, doesn't that destroy the point of using dirty rects?

Comment: I don't have a ton of experience when it comes to dirty rects, that could be your problem but I doubt it. I don't know how private you want your project but if you are willing I can take a look at it and see if I have the problem too.